# Are abrogated verses in the Lawh-al-Mahfuz (Stone Tablets)?

Tags: quran, islamic-scholar

The Quran is preserved in the stone tablets near Allah:

> Rather it is a glorious Qurʾān, in a preserved tablet.(85:21-22)

Abrogation is considered a way in which Allah changes or replaces some of the verses of the Quran:

> For any verse that We abrogate or remove from memories, We bring another which is better than it, or similar to it. Do you not know that Allah has power over all things? (2:106)

So, the question from this is whether abrogation applies to the stone tablets as well or not. I see three possibilities:

- Abrogation was done to the stone tablets as well. (I think this is unlikely because it says "preserved")
- Or the abrogated verses are in the stone tablets and were not removed.
- Or the abrogated verses were never in the stone tablets in the first place. (this might imply that those verses were somehow less "Quranic" even when they were not abrogated)

In this question, I am specifically referring to the verses that were abrogated from recitation, meaning they are not in the current Quran anymore.

So, did any of the scholars discuss this topic, and what were their conclusions regarding this?

Comment: We have both Luh-e-Mahfouz and luh-of-Mahw-and-Ithbaat. Check this [link](https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa306) for some explanation (*the page is originally in Farsi/Persian, but it has links to some other languages translations at the bottom of the page*)

Comment: https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/199285/

Comment: why you think it is stone?